# Change Emailaddress/Subscriber Key for triggered Send via REST API dynamically

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, triggered-send

I have the following API Call which is working fine with the tool postman.
Bit I am stuck with the transfer of this into a web page.

The scenario should be: A user enters his email address on a third party website and when clicking the submit button the triggered email is sended.

How do I come from that working piece to the point that the email is send to any Emailaddress? Meaning the email address and Subscriber key changes dependet from what is typed into the subscription form?

```
{
"From": {
    "Address": "info@email.com",
    "Name": "Triggered Send"
},
"To": {
    "Address": "john.doe@email.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "john.doe@email.com",
    "ContactAttributes": {
        "SubscriberAttributes": {
            "First Name": "John",
            "Last Name": "Doe"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need a developer to integrate your website with Salesforce Marketing Cloud:

1. Create an API Integration app in the [App Center](https://appcenter-auth.s1.marketingcloudapps.com/)
2. Use the [FuelSDK-Node-Auth](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-Auth) for OAuth 2.0 key management. Be sure to store your CliendID & Client Secret in a secure server.
3. Integrate your web form with the [FuelSDK-Node-REST](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-REST) to send your email dynamically to the email inserted by the client in EmailAddress field.

Comment: Thank you. That help me already. So there is any way to simulate that process inside the Marketing Cloud with the Cloud Pages ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate this process in Cloud page with a combination of Ampscript and SSIS. Note: AppCenter has been migrated into Marketing Cloud, Administration -> Install Packages, to get REST API credentials, you can create a new package, Add a "API Integration" Component, the settings are similar to the old AppCenter. Once you have the ClientID and ClientSecret for the BU.

1. Create a data extension with two fields: ClientID and ClientSecret to store your rest API credentials so it is not hard coded in cloud page.
2. Create Cloud page, retrieve API credentials from DE then use [HTTPPost2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httppost2.htm) Ampscript function to make REST API calls e.g. Authentication, TriggerSend
3. Use SSIS [Platform.Function.ParseJSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityParseJSON.htm) to parse JSON result from Ampscript HTTPPost2 result to retrieve accessToken and TriggerSend result.

Comment: Thats a very great approach! Thanks for sharing that idea.